# Is python a good choice to go with JMeter performance testing?

Tags: python, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell, post-processor

I know a little bit of python and I think its easier to understand than java. So I want to continue with python even while using JMeter. Is python a good choice to go with JMeter? I know that Beanshell supports Python but the related help documentation I did not came across. Maybe someone here can share the link? Anything related with 'python + jmeter' is welcome! Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you trying to test the performance of a python web server app with JMeter?

Comment: @CliffordCheefoon no. I want to use python as scripting language with jmeter beanshell or PostProcessors. Is that possible? if yes, is it a good choice?

Answer (score 1):

Beanshell doesn't support Python.

You can add Python support to [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) by downloading [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) jar and dropping it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) this way you will get Python in the language dropdown:

[image]

However it will not be the "good choice" as each invocation of the JSR223 Test Element will trigger the loading of Jython engine and interpreting the script.

The recommended scripting language is [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) as Groovy scripts can be compiled and cached so the performance of the script will be much higher and you will be able to achieve more throughput on the same hardware.

Comment: can you please share how one should go about learning JMeter? Where to start, what to be aware of etc? It would help me a lot, coming from an expert like you. Thank you very much.

Comment: Official [User Manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/index.html) is the best place to start with. You can also check out free [JMeter University](https://www.blazemeter.com/university/), there are basic and advanced tiers with certifications in the end. A good book on performance testing concepts in general and testing web applications in particular is [Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications](https://freecomputerbooks.com/Performance-Testing-Guidance-for-Web-Applications.html)