# How to measure website load time using Python?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, networking, python-requests, vpn

I am trying to build a benchmark tool for my own VPN to test page load times between different versions.
Would using Selenium and Navigation Timing API work? Or would even something like this `requests.get("http://example-site.com").elapsed.total_seconds()` suffice? This is for purely comparing speeds and to check if sites have blocked the connection.

Or would both of these approaches be considered poor? If so, is there any other tool that I could use? (Preferably for use with Python)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen anyone do performance testing using selenium

People tend to use JMeter to do performance testing of websites/applications...
JMeter has a guide on how to get started available below

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html

You can record a browsing session and store it on jmeter to execute the same session each time

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html

You can use JMeter along with python as seen below but if what you need is basic performance testing you should just record a browsing session with Jmeter

[Is python a good choice to go with JMeter performance testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72471596/is-python-a-good-choice-to-go-with-jmeter-performance-testing)

The getting started guide suggests using Jmeter on non gui mode, more reliable, but gui mode should be enough to perform basic tests of a VPN provider.